# How can I upgrade the built-in Apple Clang on MacOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, clang, xcode-tools

My clang  on MacOS that is provided by Apple seems to be a bit outdated.

```
> clang -v
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.9)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

But my MacOS is up to date: MacOS Ventura 13.0.1
I have recently installed Xcode version 14.1,
but I think the Xcode developer tools (CLI tools) are installed independently.

How can I upgrade the clang that is provided by Apple on MacOS?
According to [Xcode on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_12.x_(since_Free_On-Device_Development)) it looks like the clang used by Xcode is newer.

---

Some command outputs:

```
>where clang
/usr/bin/clang

>xcode-select -p
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools

>sudo xcode-select -r

xcode-select -p       
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like you've got remnants of an Xcode 12.5 installation on your system.

Things I would try/check:

- what does `where clang` say? Is it `/usr/bin/clang`?
- what's the output of `xcode-select -p`? It should be something like `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` (depending on where/how you installed Xcode).
- If the output doesn't look right, try `xcode-select -s <path>` with the path to your Xcode installation, or try resetting with `xcode-select -r`
- running `sudo xcode-select --install` may force a new installation of the commandline tools

In any case, the output of `clang -v` on my Ventura box is

> Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)
> Target: arm64-apple-darwin22.1.0
> Thread model: posix
> InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

as one would expect.

Comment: Thanks,  `sudo xcode-select -r` fixed it.